# SMALL(SUM(IF... when there are Duplicate Values and Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, sum, duplicates, match

I'm building a heavy database of football stats.  One sheet ('Stats'!) has each year's stats pasted, from 1970-present.  Sheet 'Years'! has a list of every NFL player in history, with their rookie year, final year, and career length.

On 'Stats'!, I want to pair the player's "Year # in League" with their stat row.  Suppose a player began in 1991. On his 1994 stat line, the "Year # in League" column should read "4," because it's his fourth year in the NFL.

```
'=if($I2="RB",sum(-(index(Years!$D:$D,match($G2,Years!$B:$B,0))),$F2,1),"")'
```

Stats!I : position  (separated into different workbook files, to help load times)
Stats!G : player name
Stats!F : year of this stat row
Years!B : player name
Years!D : rookie year

Problem is, there are plenty of duplicate NFL player names from the 'Years'! sheet.  So this formula draws the first match, providing some false negatives and false enormous positives (1970 is Mel Farr's -18th year in the NFL, Bob Davis' 33rd).

I figure the simplest way would be to create a SMALL function to retrieve the smallest SUM(Stats!F:F,-Years!D:D,1), including an IF or MATCH (or both) to match player name Years!$B:$B with Stats!$G2, while also confirming that Years!$D:$D

Comment: I would rephrase your question: looking for the highest carreer starting number where the name matches and the carreer ending number is higher than or equal the given year and the name matches.

Comment: Plus the starting year is lower than or equal the given year.

Comment: yes, thanks, user3819867.... i tried editing the original post, but 

"I figure the simplest way would be to create a SMALL function to retrieve the smallest SUM(Stats!F:F,-Years!D:D,1), including an IF or MATCH (or both) to match player name Years!$B:$B with Stats!$G2, while also confirming that Years!$D:$D<Stats!$F2."

Answer (score 0):

You could try an array formula like this

> =if($I2="RB",$F2-small(if(Years!$B:$B=$G2,if(Years!$D:$D< $F2,Years!$D:$D)),1),"")

Confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: thanks Barry Houdini!  but looks like this only finds the smallest career start year... 
the goal would be, like user3819867 said, to confirm 1) name match, 2) rookie year < current year, and then of those results, find the smallest sum (Current year, -rookie year, 1)

Comment: This does the name match. I'll alter so that the year must be less than current

Comment: Barry, i tried '=if($I2="RB",$F2-small(if(Years!$B:$B=$G2,if(Years!$D:$D< $F2,Years!$D:$D)),1),"")' .....  this one comes up with #NUM! (Error:  SMALL has no valid input data.), for any player that passes the "RB" step.

Comment: An array formula with entire column references??!

Comment: are you using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER so that you get curly braces round the formula? If so then #NUM! error means you have no valid rows which match - is that possible? As XOR LX implies, it's better to restrict the ranges to the actual data you have, otherwise the formulas will be slow